# Refactoring for-loop Linq query into a single query

Tags: linq, for-loop, refactoring

I have a set of data that requires some processing but I want to split the work available  threads. How can I change this into a single instruction, preferably removing the for-loop?

```
string[] keysForThread;
IEnumerable<string> allData;
List<string> dataForSingleThreadToProcess;

for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    dataForSingleThreadToProcess.AddRange(allData.Where(x => x.StartsWith(keys[i])));
```

I don't mind changing the string[] keysForThread into a List and/or the List dataForSingleThreadToProcessinto an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
var data = allData.Where(datum => keys.Any(key => datum.StartsWith(key))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Or `Count(key => datum.StartsWith(key) > 0)` for those still on .NET 3.5 :)

Comment: It was? My bad. I blame the fact that it's Friday :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct way of doing what your code does without the for loop.

```
var data = keys.SelectMany(k => allData.Where(d => d.StartsWith(k)).ToList();
```

However, Jon skeet's answer will probably be more efficient.

Comment: That said, this answer will result in the same items in the same order as your original code (I think) where JS's will result in a different order and with any duplicates (caused by e.g. keys `bo` and `b` both matching `book`) removed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
dataForSingleThreadToProcess = allData.Where(x => keys.Any(x.StartsWith)).ToList();
```

Comment: While writing this, I wasn't the only one with this idea :)